# What is the religion of the future?

Tags: philosophy-of-religion, buddhism

There's a famous quote said by Albert Einstein: "The religion of the future will be a cosmic religion.  It should transcend a personal God and avoid dogmas and theology.  Covering both the natural and the spiritual, it should be based on a religious sense arising from the experience of all things, natural and spiritual, as a meaningful unity.  Buddhism answers this description.”

I believe that actual religion teachs values and moral, but we can live in equilibrium without religion. It doesn't contribute to our happiness. 
I see that religion also generates conflits between races. And I don't agree that it should be excuse to cause any harm to anyone. I don't understand the existence of Vatican for example. To give power to such persons to harm or difame other people  just because they differ in opinions proved by scientific facts. I do believe that science contraries religion and nowadays people believe in who they want to believe. Actually, they believe in what they need to believe, so that they can live in peace. For example, there are people who can't stand the fact that we only have one life to live, so they take religion to believe that when you die you come back to start another life as another living being, and that they have many lifes lived.

①Do you think that in the future everyone will have the same religion? Do you think that's possible?

②What is the purpose of a religion? Does religion is essencial for humans to live in peace, happiness and moral?

③Do you agree with Einstein? That budism satisfies Einstein's definition of religion of the future?

Comment: There is a book by the Brazilian philosopher Roberto Unger titled exactly that: 'The religion of the Future'; which is a manifesto for a 'prophetic pragmatism' and an (a)theology; his opening chapter addresses your three questions; to which his answers would be: 1) no, 2) yes, 3) one of three options.